# Opening Files with SLPDF Extension

Tags: pdf

I have a file with SLPDF extension, it is a locked PDF file but any software can't open it. The file was locked with hardware lock and the tiny manager key creator. I don't have the key and hardware lock.

Comment: So this is a PDF file, essentially, but is locked (and probably encrypted) using a hardware key?

Comment: yes, it was locked with a hardware key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without the hardware key you are probably out of luck. Most hardware keys and the locking they provide include encryption, not simply permission control.

There is plenty of software designed to change permissions so long as you can access the actual data of the file. However, if a file is actually encrypted, unless you have the appropriate cracking applications and the hardware and time to wait for a decryption, and then a good measure of luck, the only way to decrypt the file is with the key.

UPDATED for additional info:

The issue here is that copy protection was built into your file preventing this from happening. Your request is technically asking us to assist you in breaking protections designed to prevent you from doing this.

The point is that you are working on a document the authors and owners of which do not WANT you to be able to copy, reproduce, or use in any manner besides directly from the CD on which it is stored, and to attempt to do any of this is to go against the intention of the owner, and probably against the law.

Comment: thank you, I have a CD, it has key but i can't copy it. when i use the CD, the file opens but the CD is not mine, I need a way to open the file without the CD or a way to copy the CD. (probably the CD was created with a hardware key)

Comment: Once you're decrypted the file you may be able to save it as a decrypted file that can be transfered and opened elsewhere without the key, but the key is, you need the key. :)

Comment: It was locked, I can't save, print or print screen it!!

Comment: Oh, so you have access to the file, you can view it and read it, but it is access controlled?

Comment: yes, it is :(, the file has very pages, I need to print it.